# How to add a download path to gui application in python tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, path, download

How would I add this download path to my GUI application in `tkinter` that I am making using python?

```
downloads_path = str(Path.home() / "Downloads")
```

To this

```
    with open(f"{name}.mp4", "wb") as out:
        out.write(video_bytes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already used `pathlib.Path` class, you can keep `downloads_path` as of type `pathlib.Path` instead of `string`:

```py
downloads_path = Path.home() / "Downloads"
```

Then you can use it inside 2nd code block as below:

```py
with open(downloads_path/f"{name}.mp4", "wb") as out:
    out.write(video_bytes)
```

If you still want to keep `downloads_path` as string, then you can use `os.path.join(...)` as below:

```py
import os

...

with open(os.path.join(downloads_path, f"{name}.mp4"), "wb") as out:
    out.write(video_bytes)
```